# python - unit tests logging result file

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

I need logging to file tests result which is displayed in the console:
'**Ran 1 test in 83.904s
OK**
'

my method:

```
 def allTests(self):
    testmodules = [
        #'tests.tests1',
        'tests.tests2',
        'tests.tests3'    
    ]
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    results = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    for t in testmodules:
        suite.addTest(unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromName(t))
        print results
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

and i run my test:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
timestr = time.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")
logFormatter = log.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]  %(message)s")
rootLogger = log.getLogger()
logPath = './Logs/'
fileName = '{0}--StartTests'.format(timestr)
fileHandler = log.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(logPath, fileName))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
consoleHandler = log.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
rootLogger.setLevel(log.NOTSET)
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)
log.disable(log.DEBUG)
start = startTests()
start.allTests()
```

I have all information logged except information about  end result (OK,Fail Skipped)

**Ran 1 test in 72.710s
Fail (Fail=1)**

How can I add this information ???

Please Help me, THX.

Answer (score 1):

it works
i add to :  unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite) >>> log.info( unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite))